# Passar valor da tableview para tabbar

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitabbar

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo meu primeiro app e estou com uma dúvida.

Tenho uma tableview, e gostaria que o indexpath.row dela fosse visível nas 2 viewcontroller de uma tabbar, pra carregar numa label. Tentei fazer da forma abaixo, porém não funcionou.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "detail"){
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let tabVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
        let Detalhe1 = tabVC.viewControllers![0] as! Detalhe1ViewController
        let Detalhe2 = tabVC.viewControllers![1] as! Detalhe2ViewController

        //Labels da primeira viewcontroller
        Detalhe1.ID.text = arr1[indexPath.row]
        //Labels da segunda viewcontroller
        Detalhe2.ID.text = arr2[indexPath.row]

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema parece estar aqui:

```
//Labels da primeira viewcontroller
Detalhe1.ID.text = arr1[indexPath.row]
//Labels da segunda viewcontroller
Detalhe2.ID.text = arr2[indexPath.row]
```

Você não deve passar os valores direto para os objetos da tela, pois eles são instanciados após o carregamento, neste ponto eles ainda não existem.

Crie variáveis na View de destino, e passe os valores para elas. Ai no método `viewDidLoad` da view que será mostrada, passe os valores para os componentes da tela.

```
// Table view
tabvc.detalhe1 = arr1[indexPath.row]
tabvc.detalhe2 = arr2[indexPath.row]

// View de destino
var detalhe1 : String?
var detalhe2 : String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Detalhe1.ID.text = detalhe1
    Detalhe2.ID.text = detalhe2

    self.view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
}
```

Comment: Valeu Celso, vou testar mais tarde e te falo se funcionou! Abs